# ANT+ to Bluetooth Low Energy bridge?

Tags: accessories, bike-computer

Does anyone know of a stand alone ANT+ to Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) bridge device?

I have a Garmin Edge 810, which uses ANT+ ... but I would also like to track my rides on my iPhone 5S (which has BTLE, but ANT+ is a hassle).

I'm looking for a device that will correctly bridge ANT+ to BTLE so the iPhone will pick up the data as well as my 810.  I specifically want the bridge to work with a HRM, speed/cadence sensor (combo, like Garmin GSC10), and separate speed & cadence sensors.

I've tried the 4iiii Viiiva, but it doesn't work properly due to a proprietary protocol (or just lack of adoption by the app developers).  I had high hopes for this device, but it can't provide accurate data (yet).  http://www.geekyramblings.net/2013/12/03/viiiiva-hrm/

I know about the Wahoo RFLKT, but I don't need the display and would prefer something cheaper that I can stuff in my jersey pocket or seat bag.

I need something that will handle multiple devices at the same time without dropouts.

Update 9/29:

The manual upload issue is kind of moot now, as Garmin connect can now upload my rides to Strava automatically.  I can now turn on BT at the end of my ride and the 810 will upload the ride to Garmin Connect and Garmin uploads to Strava.

The live tracking was never a critical function.

I'd still like to get some kind of bridge so I can use my ANT+ accessories on the bike when using a trainer and an iPad trainer app without having to use the Wahoo ANT adapter.  I'll probably be upgrading to a lightning based iPad and I've heard the 30 pin adapter for lightning devices tends to be iffy.

Comment: What extra functionality do you get from tracking on two devices at once?  The Garmin Edge 810 is a very high end device. What features does the iPhone offer that you feel the need to track on 2 separate devices.

Comment: Live tracking for one ... the ability to skip the manual upload after the ride is another.

Comment: Live tracking is supported out of the box with the 810 & a bluetooth connection to the phone?

Comment: @AliGibbs true, but that requires Bluetooth which is a drain on the battery (both the 810's and the phone).

Comment: Just learned about this, might be what you are looking for: http://4iiii.com/product/viva-mini/

Comment: @Kevin If it's anything like the original Viiva, then it's not going to work with most software.  I already went down that path and don't plan on doing it again.

Comment: @david - Bother.  I just heard about it and was hoping it was an updated version but I can't seem to find any confirmation that they've done an update.

Answer (score 4):

The [Wahoo RFLKT+](http://uk.wahoofitness.com/wahoo-rflkt-plus-iphone-powered-bike-computer.html) is the only device on the market as far as I am aware (and I have looked).

As a BTLE user I can tell you you're better off with ANT+; I get far more sensor drops than my ANT+ co-riders.

Answer (score 3):

A year ago I did some work investigating ANT+ and BLTE protocols during development of a mobile fitness application. The details are a bit fuzzy, but if I recall correctly, this cannot be a simple conduit that listens for ANT+ radio signals and translates to BLTE signals. The security, message structure, communication style, registration protocol, etc. are all different.  Such a device would most likely require some specific device to application translator, too (e.g. ANT+ power meter to BLTE readable by mobile app).  I think there may also be some intellectual property or licensing issues that could get in the way of a commercial product. I seem to recall the ANT+ people not being too happy about BLTE when I spoke with someone from their ORG at CES '13.  Sorry I'm unable to dig in deeper, but I think a number of technical and business factors stand in the way of a commercially available generic ANT/BLTE gateway device in the near future or perhaps never.

Answer (score 0):

I think that  what you are looking for is ANT+ sensor for you iPhone.

Unforunately this is also problematic; [there are some products on marcet](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/on-the-go/mobileaccessories/ant-adapter-for-iphone/prod103887.html) but they all are using "old" 30-pin iPhone connector. So you would need a 30-pin-to-lightning adatper like [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter).

Or you could just wait for lightning ANT+ sensor :/

Comment: No, actually, I'm looking for a device that will properly bridge ANT+ to BTLE.  I've already got an ANT+ 30 pin key that I use with my iPad and I could get an adapter to use the key with my iPhone 5S.

My Viiiva HRM will bridge ANT+ to BTLE, but apps have to be specifically designed to handle the special data stream (few are).